# simple array help in actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am doing a program where I am creating instances by arrays but I am not sure on how to get rid of them later.. to explain more clearly here is my code:

(I quickly whipped up an example...so that's why there is only one variable in the code)

```
for (var q:int = 0; q < caw1.length; q++)
{
    addChild(caw1[q]);
    caw1[q].x = 9;
    caw1[q].y = 833;
}



half2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxt2);
function nxt2(e:MouseEvent)
{
            removeChild(half2);
    removeChild(caw1[1]);
    half2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxt2);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "get rid of them later"? When do you want to get rid of them, and how? Do you want to remove them from the array, from the stage, or both?

Comment: I want to get rid of them after that half 2 event ends . just from the stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with just looping through them again?

```
function nxt2(e:MouseEvent)
{
    removeChild(half2);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < caw1.length; i++) {
        removeChild(caw[i]);
    }
    half2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxt2);
}
```

Comment: @tailedmouse Haha, no problem, everyone starts somewhere. ;)

Answer (score 0):

FP 11 later , A new method has been added. that is [`removeChildren()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildren%28%29). using a `removeChildren()` rather than using for loop with `removeChild()`. is more reasonable.

> Removes all child DisplayObject instances from the child list of the
>   DisplayObjectContainer instance. The parent property of the removed
>   children is set to null , and the objects are garbage collected if no
>   other references to the children exist.
>
> The garbage collector reallocates unused memory space. When a variable
>   or object is no longer actively referenced or stored somewhere, the
>   garbage collector sweeps through and wipes out the memory space it
>   used to occupy if no other references to it exist.

Try this:

```
function nxt2(e:MouseEvent)
{
    removeChild(half2);
    removeChildren(0,caw1.length-1);
    half2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nxt2);
}
```